# Who’s wins this pot?

Tags: texas-hold-em

To make a long hand short, 2 players are all in heads up,river comes Players 1 tables there cards and announces 2 pair, player 2 announce “he’s out” and tables his cards face up, a player not in the hand notices players 2 had a straight and corrected him. Who should have taken the pot?

Answer (score 2):

The rule in most casinos is "cards speak". If a hand is properly tabled face-up, anyone--dealer, floor, spectators--can and should assist in awarding the pot to the best hand shown.

Answer (score 1):

If player two tabled cards that didn't touch the muck they have won. I'm going to go ahead and say this is a home game as a casino/card club game with a dealer it's the dealer's responsibility to determine the winning hand and award the pot.

Cards talk. When players are all-in they cannot fold. Again cards talk. They can muck their cards facedown in an all-in situation if they wish to, however once cards are tabled it doesn't matter what the player says. So yes player 2 has the best hand, player 2 is all-in so it doesn't matter he says he is out as he has tabled his cards. Player 2 wins.